# Loop through years + months

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime

I am trying to loop through years and months. If `@user.created_at` is `November 2015`, then I'd like to get this output:

```
November 2015
December 2015
January 2016
February 2016
March 2016
```

I tried the following:

```
Hash[(@user.created_at.month..Date.today.month).map { |month| [ month, 0 ] }].merge(...)
```

But the above code returns

> stack level too deep

because it loops `11..3`. 
How can I figure out this issue?

Comment: How many years and months do you want to loop through? You can add numbers like 1.month to slowly increment through the months

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to compute the upcoming months/years you could always use [`advance`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html#method-i-advance):

```
start = @user.created_at.to_date.beginning_of_month

Hash[(0..6).collect { |n| [ start.advance(months: n).month, 0 ] }]
```

That should properly step through days/months. You may want to just stick in dates instead of just the month number.

If you want to do "up to today" then try this:

```
date = @user.created_at.to_date.beginning_of_month
stop = Date.today.beginning_of_month
hash = { }

while (date <= stop)
  hash[date] = 0

  date = date.advance(months: 1)
end
```

Comment: Thanks @tadman for the answer. Why there's `0..6.collect`? I want to do it till `now`, so I've done this: `Hash[@admin.created_at.to_date.beginning_of_month..Date.today.to_date.beginning_of_month.collect { |n| [ start.advance(months: n).month, 0 ] }]`, however got this error message: `NoMethodError (undefined method `collect' for 3:Fixnum):` - am I missing some part of converting the dates?

Comment: Oh, sure, that could work. Just be sure that in `n..m` that `n <= m`. I forgot to group the range. Edit made. Should be `(0..6)` as in "months plus zero to plus six", but you can substitute your code as well. You can't use the range unless you want to iterate over each and every day.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is turn each date into a "month number" that's the year multiplied by 12 plus the zero-based month, and then iterate over them, e.g.:

```
from_date = Date.new(2015, 11) # Nov. 1, 2015
to_date = Date.today # Mar. 22, 2016

nov2015 = from_date.year * 12 + (from_date.month - 1)
# => 24190
nov2015.divmod(12)
# => [2015, 10]

mar2016 = to_date.year * 12 + (to_date.month - 1)
# => 24194
mar2016.divmod(12)
# => [2016, 2]
```

Remember that the months are zero-based, so `2` is March and `10` is November. As expected, `nov2015` and `mar2016` have a difference of four. Now we can iterate from one to the other:

```
nov2015.upto(mar2016) do |month_num|
  year, month = month_num.divmod(12)
  puts Date.new(year, month + 1).strftime("%B %Y")
end
# => November 2015
#    December 2015
#    January 2016
#    February 2016
#    March 2016
```

Perfect! But it's better if we can put this into a method that returns an Enumerator so we can use any of the Enumerable methods (`each`, `map`, `each_cons`, you name it) on it:

```
def months_enum(from_date, to_date)
  from = from_date.year * 12 + from_date.month - 1
  to = to_date.year * 12 + to_date.month - 1

  Enumerator.new do |y|
    from.upto(to) do |n|
      year, month = n.divmod(12)
      y << Date.new(year, month + 1)
    end
  end
end
```

Then:

```
from = Date.new(2015, 11, 1)
to = Date.today

months_enum(from, to).each do |date|
  puts date.strftime("%Y-%m")
end
# -> 2015-11
#    2015-12
#    2016-01
#    2016-02
#    2016-03

p months_enum(from, to).map {|date| date.strftime("%B %Y") }
# => [ "November 2015",
#      "December 2015",
#      "January 2016",
#      "February 2016",
#      "March 2016" ]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'date'
from_date = Date.new(2015, 11)
to_date   = Date.today

until from_date > to_date do
  puts from_date.strftime("%B %Y")
  from_date = from_date.next_month
end

#November 2015
#December 2015
#January 2016
#February 2016
#March 2016
```

Comment: Hi @steenslag, thanks for your answer. I am trying to make it work, but the output will always stop on February, it never goes to March.

Comment: @user984621 I switched 2 lines of code (the `puts..`and the `from_date = from_date...` lines). Maybe you are testing the "old" version.

Answer (score 0):

I would begin with the user created_at date and loop through until it has caught up to today:

```
start = @user.created_at
months = []
while start <= Time.zone.now
  months << [start.strftime('%B'), start.year]
  start += 1.month
end
months
```

Result:

```
=> [["November", 2015], ["December", 2015], ["January", 2016], ["February", 2016], ["March", 2016]]
```

This way you don't have to calculate the difference in months between created_at and now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure-Ruby solution.

```
require 'date'
```

If given

```
prev_date = "November 2015"
m = Date.strptime(prev_date,"%B %Y")
  #=> #<Date: 2015-11-01 ((2457328j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

then

```
n = Date.today
n -= n.day - 1
  #=> #<Date: 2016-03-01 ((2457449j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

while m <= n
  puts "#{Date::MONTHNAMES[m.month].ljust(8)} #{m.year}"
  m = m >> 1
end

November 2015
December 2015
January  2016
February 2016
March    2016
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding months to a date object in Rails using the `Integer#month()` method will take care of all the wrapping of years for you. It's also smart enough to not skip a month with less than 31 days should the user's join date fall on the 31st of some month. If you add a month to January 31st, the return value will be February 28th (or 29th in the case of a leap year).

```
date_joined = @user.created_at
now = Time.now

until date_joined.month > now.month && date_joined.year == now.year
  puts date_joined.strftime("%B %Y")
  date_joined += 1.month
end
```